# I am a non-arab. If I mispronounce words in salah, am I invalidating my prayer?

Tags: salat

If I mispronounce words in salah, will it invalidate my prayer?

For example, if I am reciting surah al nas, and in that, if I say 'qul audu..' instead of qul a'uzu, will it invalidate my prayer?

Also am I invalidating my salah if I mispronounce:
a) ط as ت

b) ذ as د

c) ص as س

d) ق as ك

e) ه as ح

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q &A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. You shouldn't stop trying to learn pronouncing it more correctly.

Comment: But my question still remains unanswered. Does mispronouncing words invalidate my prayer?